# Javascript - Rock, Paper, scissors with switch statement? If not what are alternatives?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I am running the following codes bellow it only prints 'Draw!' the other cases does not work, what am I doing wrong?

```js
const rps = (p1, p2) => {
var s = 'scissors';
var p = 'paper';
var r = 'rock';
var ans = '';

switch (rps) {
case (p1 == p && p2 == r):case (p1 == s && p2 == p): case (p1 == r && p2 == s):
ans = ('Player 1 won!');
break;

case (p1 == s && p2 == r): case (p1 == r && p2 == p): case (p1 == p && p2 == s):
ans =  ('Player 2 won!');
break;

default: ans =  ('Draw!');
break;
}
return ans
}


 rps('paper','scissors')
```

Comment: You are looking for `if`/`else`, not `switch` - which is not made for the evaluation of boolean conditions

Answer (score 1):

`switch` compares the value you put in (`rps` which is a function) with each `case` (which will be `true` or `false`).

Since the function never matches a boolean, you always end up hitting the default case.

> what am I doing wrong?

Trying to use `switch` for something it isn't really suited to.

Use `if` and `else` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
let rock = 2;
let scissors = 4;
let paper = 8;

let firstPlayerChoice = rock;
let secondPlayerChoice = paper;
 
switch (firstPlayerChoice / secondPlayerChoice) {
  case 1:
    console.log('there is a tie! pick again');
    break;
  case 0.5:
  case 4:
    console.log(`first player won!`);
    break;
  case 2:
  case 0.25:
    console.log(`second player won!`);
    break;
  default:
    console.log('something went wrong!');
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the creativity  I don't think a switch makes sense here tho

Answer (score -1):

¡Hello!,

You are misunderstanding the use of "switch", the switch works like this:

> The switch expression is evaluated once.
>
> The value of the expression is compared with the values of each case.
>
> If there is a match, the associated block of code is executed.

Soruce: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Like Quentin says, use "if" instead