# Alternative of "if statement" with "switch statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm currently write the litte Scissors, paper, rock game and I used "If statement" to do so. Now, I try to write it with the "switch statement". So I will show you what I wrote but nothing happen in my console and I don't know why. Seems pretty easy for anybody used to code everyday I think.

**So I begin to declare my variables.**

```
let rock = 'rock';
let scissors = 'scissors';
let paper = 'paper';
```

**then these two variables will be changed to test the conditional**

```
let firstPlayerChoice = paper;
let secondPlayerChoice = rock;
```

**After that I made my seven possibilities**

```
let firstPossibility = firstPlayerChoice === paper && secondPlayerChoice === rock;
let secondPossibility = firstPlayerChoice === scissors && secondPlayerChoice === paper;
let thirdPossibility = firstPlayerChoice === rock && secondPlayerChoice === scissors;

let fourthPossibility = firstPlayerChoice === rock && secondPlayerChoice === paper;
let fifthPossibility = firstPlayerChoice === paper && secondPlayerChoice === scissors;
let sixthPossibility = firstPlayerChoice === scissors && secondPlayerChoice === rock;

let seventhPossibility = firstPlayerChoice === secondPlayerChoice;
```

**So, now I create my condition using my Switch statement but nothing is running on my console. The fact is I have difficulties to identify the good expression.**

```
switch (firstPlayerChoice) {
    case firstPlayerChoice === paper && secondPlayerChoice === rock:
    case firstPlayerChoice === scissors && secondPlayerChoice === paper:
    case firstPlayerChoice === rock && secondPlayerChoice === scissors:
        console.log('First Player won !');
        break;
}

switch (secondPlayerChoice) {
    case fourthPossibility:
    case fifthPossibility:
    case sixthPossibility:
        console.log('Second player won !');
        break;
}
```

**Someone can provide me just one expression to help to understand the big picture please ?**

Comment: `firstPlayerChoice` is neither `true` nor `false`, so how will it ever be able to match expressions like `firstPlayerChoice === paper && secondPlayerChoice === rock`? Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Not sure what you mean by _“provide […] just one expression to help […] understand the big picture”_, but see the linked Q&A.

Comment: Ok thanks Sebastian, it helps me to see the point.

Comment: Your scenario however with `switch` does not take into account the case of a tie. Because boolean can only be `true` or `false`, I feel you miss some way of computing a tie but some other solutions have tried to use [numbers instead of booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186956/javascript-rock-paper-scissors-with-switch-statement-if-not-what-are-altern
) to solve that with switch statement.